# ImportError: No module named rl.algorithms.deepq

Tags: python, python-2.7, import, anaconda

I cloned the repo from here: https://github.com/wingedsheep/rl

I now tried to run the code,

```
cd rl
python examples/runner_lunarlander.py
```

I get the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "examples/runner_lunarlander.py", line 10, in <module>
    from rl.algorithms.deepq import DeepQ
ImportError: No module named rl.algorithms.deepq
```

The error comes from line 10:

```
from rl.algorithms.deepq import DeepQ
```

DeepQ is a class in the file deepq.py.

I saw init file present in all the folders.

I am using anaconda with python 2.7.

I can't get how to resolve this. Please help. Thanks.

Comment: Try `python -m examples.runner_lunarlander.py`

Comment: @DavidGomes I get /home/sietw/anaconda2/envs/tensorflow/bin/python: Import by filename is not supported.

Comment: @DavidGomes Thanks, anyway I don't have to do that. What can I do to make the code run as it is. Why is the error coming. plz explain a bit. thx.

Answer (score -1):

Your are getting this error because the module (code) you're trying to run is not on your python's PYTHONPATH. PYTHONPATH environment variable is responsible to update and inform python where to look for imports. There are lot of ways for setting it.

You could add this in your ~/.bashrc file for more permanent user-wise setup:

```
export PYTHONPATH="${PYTHONPATH}:/home/sie/src/
```

or for this particular (bash I assume) session, just run:

```
export PYTHONPATH="${PYTHONPATH}:/home/sie/src/
python examples/runner_lunarlander.py
```

Don't use /home/sie/src/rl, where the root of the clone relies, the parent folder should do the job for you.